# What does this notation mean? $ f \in C^0 ([0,1] , W^{3,2} (K) ) $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

$$ f \in C^0 ([0,1] , W^{3,2} (K) ) $$

Here $W^{n,m}$ is a Sobolev Space, and K is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ .

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $f$ is a function defined on $[0, \infty) \times \mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is a continuous map from the unit interval into the function space $W^{3,2}(K)$.

**Edit** (after OP made his question more precise):

If $f:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

then $t\mapsto f(t, .)$ may be viewed as a map from the positive real axis to maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

By restriction (on both arguments), such a map gives rise to a map $[0,1]\rightarrow \{\phi: K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$. Then your notation means that for this restriction the first sentence of my answer applies.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. $f$ was a function defined on $[0,∞) \times \mathbb R^3 $.

Comment: Then the notation says that the corresponding restriction of  the first argument of $f$ to $[0,1]$, when viewed as a map from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}$, has the property I wrote down.